# DT Display total sums per column in header row

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

DT does not provide a built-in total sum header row.
The next requirements need to be covered by the solution:

- first header row should display the 'original' column names.
- the second header row displays the total sum per column (over all rows which are visualized in the datatable. Pagination is enabled, but need to be 'ignored' during the calculations of the total sum per column).
- once a cell has been edited, the new total sum needs to be displayed.
- filtering is enabled as well. After a filter has been applied, the new total sum needs to be displayed.

I've tried multiple ways to accomplish above, but I'm stuck at below code sample.
Could you point me in the right direction?

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

# Create sample data
data <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(45*5), ncol=5))
colnames(data) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")

# Calculate column sums
colSums <- colSums(data)

# Create Shiny app
ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    # print(data)
    datatable(data, editable = TRUE, rownames = FALSE, options = list(pageLength = 10),
              # Add column names and sums to table header
              container = htmltools::withTags(table(
                class = 'display',
                thead(
                  tr(
                    lapply(colnames(data), th)
                  ),
                  tr(
                    lapply(colSums, function(x) th(x))
                  )
                )
              )))
  })
  
  # Update column sums if table is edited
  observeEvent(input$table_cell_edit, {
    cell <- input$table_cell_edit
    data[cell$row, cell$col] <<- cell$value
    colSums <<- colSums(data)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: There is an open issue about it: https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/704

Comment: I know this is just a reproducible example, but I would avoid using the name `colSums`, especially when you are also using that function in the same environment.

Answer (score 2):

Until they implement this as a new feature, here is a possibility.

By making `data` a reactive value, when it is updated by the event observer this will trigger `renderDataTable` to re-render and update the values.

```r
library(DT)
library(shiny)

# Create sample data
data <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(45*5), ncol=5))
colnames(data) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")

# Create Shiny app
ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  data <- reactiveVal(data)
  
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    totals <- unname(colSums(data()))
    nm <- colnames(data())
    datatable(data(), editable = TRUE, rownames = FALSE, options = list(pageLength = 10),
              # Add column names and sums to table header
              container = htmltools::withTags(table(
                class = "display",
                thead(
                  tr(
                    lapply(nm, th)
                  ),
                  tr(
                    lapply(totals, th)
                  )
                )
              ))
    )
  })
  
  # Update column sums if table is edited
  observeEvent(input$table_cell_edit, {
    data(editData(data(), input$table_cell_edit, rownames = FALSE))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to enable filtering and calculate (+ display) the sum based on the filtered rows?

Comment: What kind of filtering did you have in mind?

Comment: I would like to enable the default filter='top'. Let's say the table contains 50 rows without any filter. Once the user put a filter value in column A and B, only 30 rows are visualized. The display total (per column) should be calculated based on the sum of the 30 rows (per column).

Answer (score 1):

With `server=FALSE` you don't need to deal with a reactive dataframe.

```r
opts <- list(
  headerCallback = JS(
    "function(thead, data, start, end, display) {",
    "  var api = this.api();",
    "  for(var i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {",
    "    $(api.column(i).header()).html(",
    "      api.column(i, {page: 'all'}).data().reduce(function(a, b) {",
    "        if(isNaN(a)) return ''; return a + b;",
    "      })",
    "    );",
    "  }",
    "}")
)

library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(iris[,1:4], rownames = FALSE, options = opts, editable = TRUE)
  }, server = FALSE)
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Note the ugly totals.... you can use the JavaScript function `toFixed` to truncate after one decimal digit.

Comment: Great solution! Is it possible to use the headerCallback while using `server=TRUE` as well?

Comment: @Odrai Hmm I don't remember why I thought this was not possible... better to give a try.

Comment: Does not seem to work when using `server=TRUE`. Only the sum of the current page will be displayed.

Comment: @Odrai yes, that's what I thought.

Comment: If I would like to use `server=TRUE`, is the only option the solution of @LMc or is it still somehow possible to use the headerCallback?

Comment: @Odrai And I think  the totals would not be updated when you edit a cell.

Comment: @Odrai The `headerCallback` way won't work because with `server = TRUE`, because only the visible data are loaded in the table with this option.