# DT client side rendering is slow

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

A table (using DT) displays (max.) 10.000 rows (using dom='ltipr'). Loading and filtering (filter='top') data is slow. I need to use client-side rendering. Are there any options available to improve the performance (preferably the performance of server-side). E.g. setting deferRender to 'TRUE' doesn't improve the rendering time.

- Why is filtering so slow - all data is at the client? (The initial load could be slow, because all 10.000 rows need to be send to the client (acceptable), but I would assume filtering should be fast.)

Comment: Why do you need to use the client-side rendering?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent client-side rendering is required in order to use a headerCallback which displays and calculates the total per column. Filtering, cell editing, pagination and ordering are enabled (after filtering and/or cell editing the totals should be re-calculated without re-rendering the complete table). Therefore client-side rendering is used. **I would expect filtering to be quick when all data is already at the client.** Related to [DT Display total sums per column in header row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77030228/1974344)

Comment: I noticed filtering on numeric columns (with sliders) are relatively quick, but string columns are not.